# How to solve this summation?

Tags: combinatorics, summation

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \cdot (-1)^k \cdot 3^{n-k}$$

I tried generating the series. However, I don't know what to do beyond that.

Comment: HINT: your sum is given by $$2^n\cdot 3^{n-1}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Huh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall the binomial equality 
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk x^k y^{n-k} = (x+y)^n $$
Now apply this for $x = -1$ and $y = 3$.